# practical situation to use an abstract interface?

Tags: java, interface

I was trying to understand when it can be useful to create an abstract interface.

I know that if you create an interface the methods have to be public, so is nice for a service. But what happens if service is an abstract interface? Does that make sense?

If I create a service declared abstract interface and some methods are private, the class that implements this interface sees the private methods and the other (another application's or similar) doesn't see this methods, correct?

I this is a correcte implementation?

Finally after a lot of people that can sleep by my fault I write my solution, ty for waiting.

```
package cat.base.gpt.domini;
public interface IExpMS extends Serializable{
... methods here..
}

public interface IExpMSDetallGIM extends IExpMS { 
more methods here..
}


public interface IExpMSDetallOGC extends IExpMS{
..no methods just inheritance.
}

package cat.base.gpt.domini.impl;
import cat.base.gpt.domini.IClauExpedient;
import cat.base.gpt.domini.IExpMS;
public class ExpMS implements IExpMS{
..atributs and @overide methos interface
}
public class ExpMSDetallGim extends ExpMS implements IExpMSDetallGIM {..}
public class ExpMSDetallOGC extends ExpMS implements IExpMSDetallOGC  {..}
```

*every method is public, atributs are private. maybe i can write methods in the interfaces protected, but i'm not really sure...if someone needs to see full code i can't post or send by email.

if ypu wanna see the databasze views to think about my solution here there are:

[image: generic views]
[image: IExpMS]
[image: IExpMSDEtallOGC]
![IExpMSDetallGIM[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vHIG.png)

ty.

[image]

Comment: Not sure about your language, but interfaces are abstract *by definition*.

Comment: i'm working with java..is the same?so interface = abstract interface?

Comment: Does Java have Abstract Interface? It is abstract Class.

Comment: Also, private methods can not be overridden - as thez are not "seen" by any other classes, other than the one that defines it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces are always abstract. They define the `interface` of a class, so they are only about public methods, regardless the language, I think.

And while private methods are *implementation detail* and NOT the *interface*, they cannot be declared in an interface.

If you want a private method to be the same in a set of classes, you can create a base abstract class with protected methods.

**Abstract** means "you cannot create a member of this type".

**Interface** is just a *description* of some of the classes' properties. They are always abstract, while you cannot create an instance of an interface.

Look at the link http://www.ronaldwidha.net/2008/06/16/a-good-example-of-abstract-class-vs-interface/ - it describes the code in C#, but it's the same thing, only the keywords differ.

Comment: it's hard to understand..i need to read more, so if i want private methods needs to be an abstract class...

Comment: Take a look at the link I've just added.

Comment: ty, i hope help you some day.

Answer (score 2):

> i'm working with java..is the same?so interface = abstract interface?

In Java 7, yes.  In Java 7 (or earlier) an `interface` is implicitly abstract.  The interface itself does not include bodies for any of the methods that it specifies, so it makes no sense to create an instance.

In Java 8, it is possible to include `default` methods in an `interface`.  These default methods have bodies with executable code in them, but (naturally) they cannot refer directly to the state of an instance.  (Instance state variables are declared in the classes that implement interface ... and the `default` methods can't refer to stuff that has not, and may not ever be declared.)

However, you still cannot create an instance of a Java 8 `interface`, so it is still abstract in the sense that an `abstract` class is abstract.

You then ask this:

> If I create a service declared abstract interface and some methods are private, the class that implements this interface sees the private methods and the other (another application's or similar) doesn't see this methods, correct?

That is correct ... but it is nothing to do with what the `abstract` keyword means in Java.  In fact, that is describing how all Java classes behave ... vis-a-vis the visibility of `private` members.

Answer (score 2):

The primary purpose of interfaces is to allow *multiple* different implementations of "the same thing". The user of the interface is not dependent on the particular implementation and this allows for good separation of concerns. New implementations can be added later and the program can be extended, without ever need to modify the code that is using them.

Imagine how you would write a program for summing up numbers from various data sources. You could write one separate program for every type of data source (e.g. csv, xls, database table). But then, the "summing up" logic would be repeated. If you wanted to add a new data source type, you'd have to write a whole program from scratch.

Interfaces allow to make it more flexible. You realize, that your summing up logic needs to operate on a list of numbers. It doesn't care where those numbers come from. So you define an interface:

```
 interface NumberListProvider {
     List<Double> readNumbers();
 }
```

Then you make your whole complex algorithm dependent only on this interface and you provide different implementations (concrete classes), reading the numbers from csv, xls or various databases.